# SoftLayer Ruby API - Edit fields for a given IP in a subnet?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I edit the 'Description' and 'Notes' fields with SoftLayer Ruby API for a given IP in a subnet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'softlayer_api'
sl_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => "...", :api_key => "...")
sl_client['SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress'].object_with_id(ip_address_id).editObject('note'=>'success!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/editObject method has as parameter an object so you need to send that object.

try this:

```
sl_client['SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress'].object_with_id(ip_address_id).editObject({'note'=>'success!'})
```

and as you can see here http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress there is no a field description for the object so you cannot edit that field.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'


softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => 'set me',
                                         :api_key => 'set me')


service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress')


ip_address_id = 29835496
service_ref = service.object_with_id(ip_address_id)


object_template = {
    'note'=> 'test-noteEdited'
}


begin
  result = service_ref.editObject(object_template)
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  puts result.inspect

rescue => e
  puts 'Error when executing the script...'

  $stdout.print(e.inspect)
end
```

Regarding to “description”, there is not a IP address property related to this, please see:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress

For that reason, we cannot change the values for this.

References:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/editObject